# have to process 512×512 pixel image will it be possible in Qiskit. what hardware requirement will be?

Tags: qiskit

I'm working on Quantum image processing of satellite images. I'm completely a beginner also I'm learning it by my own that's why I need help. Can you please help me out I want to process the image of crop fields taken by satellite in Qiskit? I have done basic Edge detection by QHED. Now how I should proceed for it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need 9 qubit for the processing!!
read this
https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/image-processing-frqi-neqr.html